# CMake: Generated input dependency to configure_file

Tags: cmake

I would like to run `configure_file()` whose input file is generated using `add_custom_command`, through a custom dependency, before installing the output of configure_file.

I'm in reality using a ruby script to read a cmake formatted file, to extract
a few definitions which i can convert to Ruby constants in a separate library. Thus, i require the configure_file such that cmake can replace its internal variables in the ruby generated file, whose goal is to export these variables.

Thus far, I've attempted the following:

```
# Custom command to build the out.rb.in
add_custom_command (
  OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb.in"
  COMMAND ruby ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build_ruby_output.rb
  -i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/input.cmake
  -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb.in
)

# Custom target is required to build it
add_custom_target (
  dummy_target_xxx ALL DEPENDS
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb.in"
)

configure_file ( 
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb.in"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb"
)

install (
  FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb"
  DESTINATION "${RUBY_VENDOR_LIBDIR}/myvendor"
)
```

CMake complains with the error

```
CMake Error: File /home/user/myproject/build/output.rb.in does not exist.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
```

when running an out-of-tree build. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`configure_file()` is executed *immediately* at `configuration` step, while `add_custom_command()` add command to be executed(and dependency to be evaluated) at `build` step.

You may either replace `add_custom_command` with appropriate `execute_process` call, so your ruby script will be executed at `configuration` step, and its output file will be ready for `configure_file`.

Or you may replace `configure_file` with appropriate `add_custom_command`, so your file will be configured at `build` step, and will see dependencies. The problem here that you should explicitely pass CMake variables, used in "output.rb.in" file, to the configuration program, which can be, e.g.,

```
${CMAKE_COMMAND} [-D<var-definition>]+ -P <cmake-script-file-which-calls-configure_file>
```

Comment: If you are using `execute_process` on some source to give the input to `configure_file` (or in my case to define variables for replacement) - then I suggest adding those sources to the global `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` property, so *CMake* will re-run the configuration stage if those files are modified, and in doing so regenerate the configured file with the new values.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it was sufficient to reorder to configuration operation, by performing `configure_file()` first, and pipe the output of this into the custom command.. I was merely thinking of the ordering all wrong.

I still do not have an answer for adding generated dependency to the input of `configure_file()`

Complete code

```
configure_file ( 
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/input.cmake"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb.in"
)

# Custom command to build the output.rb
add_custom_command (
  OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb"
  COMMAND ruby ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build_ruby_output.rb
  -i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb.in
  -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb
)

# Custom target is required to build it
add_custom_target (
  dummy_target_xxx ALL DEPENDS
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb"
)

install (
  FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.rb"
  DESTINATION "${RUBY_VENDOR_LIBDIR}/myvendor"
)
```